# Axios - Passing parameters - Dollar Sign and Brackets

Tags: javascript, json, parameters, vue.js

i have a link to a json file:

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx(var1='100',var2='200')?$format=json

Currently I am accessing the .json file via Axios:

```
  methods: {
fetchData() {
  var config = {
    url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
      'format': 'json'
    },
  responseType: 'json'
  }
  this.axios(config)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.data = data)
```

The thing is, the $ Dollar Sign in the link is needed for accessing the json.
But I can't put it in the params to add it to the link.

The other thing is, I want to let the user input var1 and var2 on the site, and depending on that the JSON file shall be generated.

Can I accomplish that?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. :)

Greetz,
Simon

Comment: Mainly, link like this `http://xxx.xxx.xxx(var1='100',var2='200')?$format=json`, is invalid. And vue-resource is deprecated.

Comment: What to use then?

Comment: @sleepysimond Read this blog article from Vue creator about vue-resource and alternatives: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Comment: Axios is working now instead of vue-resource.
Still, same problem & question. :)

Comment: Axios is good choice, I am using it too.

Comment: Do you know how to work with the dollar sign $ and the parameters value1 and value2?

Comment: Why can't you simply use `'$format': 'json'` in params?

Comment: can you show the link when you replace the xxx.xxx.xxx with something that resembles the final link? (use a fake domain or whatever)

Comment: Nit: thanks. had the same idea a few secs ago. works.
DoXicK: http://exampleURL.com/json/data(name='Mike',age='25')?$format=json

Comment: @sleepysimon Correct uri should look like this: 
`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?var1=100&var2=200&$format=json`

Comment: Asked my programmier just yet - i have to use the format with the brackets. Isn't there a possibilty to change the format?

Comment: @sleepysimon Ask your programmer again for correct URL. This `http://xxx.xxx.xxx(var1='100',var2='200')?$format=json` will NEVER work.

Comment: Maybe with append to url parameters? :)